# Method dominator message in CAT.NET

Tags: c#, .net, security

I have installed CAT.NET to analyze a binary.
This is a VS 2013, EF project with output as Class Library.

During the analysis it reports this:

> Disabling method dominator caching due to excessive memory usage.

There is no information regarding that message in the output html.

What does this mean and where can I find more info.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with this tool. I opened the task manager during a dll scan and saw that the memory was increasing quickly, after that the tool showed the message, the memory usage decreased and the scan finished in a few seconds. It seems like the tool has a memory usage prevent system and I didn't find any information about it.

What I found was that this tool wasn't seem to be in code maintaining (the tool was released more than 3 years ago) and the version 2.0 never was released, in fact the 2.0 beta version was removed from the download repository. In the next link, there is a discussion, including Microsoft's developers opinions and the reason why they removed the file, but there isn't opinion about the new release http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/31663b6d-254e-48ce-8345-3355cb8b6023/whats-the-status-of-catnet-20?forum=catnet.

I ignore the reason why you use this tool, personally I chose it to prevent sql injection attacks. I did a very simple example to prove it:

```
 internal static List<Category> GetCategoryNames(CategoryRequest request)
  {        

     string sql = @"select classId, name from class where name like %"+ request.Name + "%";

     return SqlUtils.ExecuteList(sql, "dbname", CategoryNameMapper);

  }
```

and the tool didn't show me any risk in the report. I found another guy with the same problem http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c99de49d-c541-40df-bb85-de5951261e0c/using-catnet-to-check-for-security-vulnarabilities-better-tool-available?forum=clr

That's why I decided to look around another options, if I find another tools with similar issues, I let you know.

Regards,
Omar.